# Access local file server through Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, cmd, jenkins-workflow

I have a code repository in a file server present in the LAN.I would like to access it through Jenkins.Any help is welcome.

Regards,
Newbie_in

Comment: You need to give more information of what type of file server/code repository, you want to access. Is it a git/cvs repo.

you can directly traverse to your host machine by "execute shell" option Under "BUILD"

Comment: It is a normal file server in LAN.I tried to traverse directly to the host machine by "execute shell " option Under "BUILD" by mapping the drive but was denied access even after giving my credentials.I do not know what repository it is,but the folder contains normal C code.It will be helpful  if you could state in what repository type this folder falls in and how to access it. Regards,Newbie_in

Comment: In execute shell first check where are you by "whoami" and "pwd" commands.
Then traverse accordingly to the desired location. Also verify all the commands manually on the shell before triggering it from Jenkins environment.
if permission is denied check that folder is given Jenkins user permission's or alternatively give 777 in case of doubt.

Generally Jenkins home directory is "/var/lib/jenkins" . once you try above steps you will have better understanding

Answer (score 0):

These are the following steps that solved the above problem for me.I do not know if it is the correct way,but it works.
             To access a file server in LAN(or UNC path) through Jenkins we have to change the log on of the Jenkins services.It is done by the following steps.

1.On the startup menu,type "Services".

2.In the Services dialog box,find out Jenkins in the list.

3.Right click on Jenkins and to go to properties.

4.Go to Log On

5.Select "this account"

6.In the user section give "Domain\Username" and password that has access to         the file server in the UNC path(LAN).

7.Then reboot system to apply changes.

8.After reboot it is possible to access the UNC path through "Execute shell" of Jenkins.

Hope this helps.
Newbie_in